# How to use Scratch image in docker without command?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

This is the `scratch.Dockerfile` file

```
FROM scratch
```

and this is a `docker-compose` file

```
version: '3'
networks:
  common_network:
    name: common_network
    driver: bridge
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: scratch.Dockerfile 
    container_name: apps
    env_file:
      - .env
```

Running command  `docker-compose up -d` reports error

**Error response from daemon: No command specified**

Comment: A container is a wrapper around a single process, but the `scratch` built-in image contains absolutely nothing at all.  What are you hoping the container will do?

Comment: @DavidMaze The `.env` file contains the path of `docker-compose` files of 13 microservices and it is used to run all of them (I know that I can run them just by `.env` file). I need to share a common network among the `nginx` of all microservices. To do so, I created a network in this master `docker-compose` file, and inside every `docker-compose` file of each microservice, I will use this network as external.